# Create canonical question for sources of weather data?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[Barry Carter](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/3856/barry-carter) started the question [Sources of weather data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data) "*to create a community wiki answer for sources of weather data (both current and historical), since it gets asked so often*".

Sounds like a great idea, but we should put some effort into it to get it started.

I already made several comments below the question, but let's make these a proposal.

Some suggestions:

1. In order to be able to compare the datasets (*Which one is suitable for my purpose*?) a set of standardized parameters of the data in the set would help. I suggest additions in the format:
   [types of data][period][time resolution][geographic area]
   Examples:
   [precipitation, wind speeds, temperatures][1960-current][daily][world]
   [temperatures][1600-current][monthly][arctic]
2. The question needs to be found. We cannot close past questions as duplicates. I suggest either editing in or commenting on past questions with the remark:
   *Questions about sources of weather data have been combined into the community wiki question [Sources of weather data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data). Please add further answers over there.*
   Editing this in would be the most obvious, but IMO that feels a bit like intruding on the OPs intention - then a comment would be better.
   Candidate questions for this can be found by searching for keywords like weather, rain, snow, ...
   Would we have to mention this meta-question too?
3. Answers from those questions should be copied here. We can leave a comment under each:
   *Questions about sources of weather data have now been combined into the community wiki question [Sources of weather data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data). Can you copy your answer over there, [name]?* (that leaves the credit with them).
   If the original author has not done that in a month, someone else can do it refering to the original answer with attribution:
   *This answer was originally written by [name]. It was copied to this community wiki question from [here]*.
   The copy should be a community wiki, of course.

Please comment on 1) 2) 3) or add 4)...